# jQuery multiple ajax calls inside for loop logging same responses

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My code is something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < stf_file_names.length; i++) {
    var temp_file_name = stf_file_names[i];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php_scripts/some_script.php",
        data: {
            stf_file_name: temp_file_name
        },
        timeout: 600000,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("SUCCESS : ", response);
            //pausecomp(2000);
        }
    });
}
```

Here, some_script.php updates a database in the backend and echo's the primary key of the updated row, which is a number. But when I'm logging using the success function, I can see that it is logging only the primary key echoed by the last ajax call multiple times.

But if I use some kind of sleep function, which is pausecomp() in this case, it prints different the primary keys echoed.

I have looked at multiple stackoverflow questions regarding this and have not been to solve it.

Comment: It will log whatever the server returns.

Comment: But then, why should the output change if I uncomment the sleep function?

Comment: consider looping inside success callback or using Promises:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`async: false` will do the job

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "php_scripts/some_script.php",
        data:
```

However, this is not recommended, Better to make a loop by calling a function recursively from success.

Here is the example.

```
i=0;
function loop_stf_file_names(i){

    var temp_file_name = stf_file_names[i];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php_scripts/some_script.php",
        async: false,
        data: {
            stf_file_name: temp_file_name
        },
        timeout: 600000,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("SUCCESS : ", response);
            if( i < stf_file_names.length ){
                loop_stf_file_names( ++i );
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax()` is a async function.

By looping over ajax you are most probably sending the same data in all requests, due to which you are receiving same key for all requests.

Just sure , you send the next request when you have received the response from first request.